# Is it possible to load url and get the browser rendered DOM object using Jest or any other testing library/framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, mocha.js, jestjs

I want to get the browser rendered DOM object rather than mocking DOM object. Is it possible to load url and get the browser rendered DOM object using Jest or any other unit testing library/framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer for that, it will give you access to the `document` object.
There is also https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer for better integration with jest.